# How to convert string into integer without using Regex in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame looks like this:

[image: car_sales DataFrame]

Now i try to use the following command:

```
car_sales['Price'] = car_sales['Price'].str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '').astype(int)
```

As well as

```
car_sales['Price'] = car_sales['Price'].astype(str).str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '').astype(int)
```

But i get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[87], line 1
----> 1 car_sales['Price'] = car_sales['Price'].astype(str).str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '').astype(int)
      2 car_sales

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:6324, in NDFrame.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   6317     results = [
   6318         self.iloc[:, i].astype(dtype, copy=copy)
   6319         for i in range(len(self.columns))
   6320     ]
   6322 else:
   6323     # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 6324     new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   6325     return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   6327 # GH 33113: handle empty frame or series

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:451, in BaseBlockManager.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    448 elif using_copy_on_write():
    449     copy = False
--> 451 return self.apply(
    452     "astype",
    453     dtype=dtype,
    454     copy=copy,
    455     errors=errors,
    456     using_cow=using_copy_on_write(),
    457 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:352, in BaseBlockManager.apply(self, f, align_keys, **kwargs)
    350         applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    351     else:
--> 352         applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    353     result_blocks = extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    355 out = type(self).from_blocks(result_blocks, self.axes)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:511, in Block.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, using_cow)
    491 """
    492 Coerce to the new dtype.
    493 
   (...)
    507 Block
    508 """
    509 values = self.values
--> 511 new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    513 new_values = maybe_coerce_values(new_values)
    515 refs = None

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\astype.py:242, in astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy, errors)
    239     dtype = dtype.numpy_dtype
    241 try:
--> 242     new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
    243 except (ValueError, TypeError):
    244     # e.g. _astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings
    245     #  trying to convert to float
    246     if errors == "ignore":

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\astype.py:187, in astype_array(values, dtype, copy)
    184     values = values.astype(dtype, copy=copy)
    186 else:
--> 187     values = _astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
    189 # in pandas we don't store numpy str dtypes, so convert to object
    190 if isinstance(dtype, np.dtype) and issubclass(values.dtype.type, str):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\astype.py:138, in _astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    134     raise ValueError(msg)
    136 if copy or is_object_dtype(arr.dtype) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
    137     # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 138     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    140 return arr.astype(dtype, copy=copy)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$4,000.00'
```

Comment: The default value of `regex` in [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) changed to `False` IIRC. Do you want `regex=True`? Note that this will result in `$4,000.00` --> `400000`... so your regex may need tweaked.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text/data/code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341); post the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or a [table](/editing-help#tables). You can use `print(car_sales)` to get a plaintext version of the dataframe.

Comment: A simple method in your case could be to use `car_sales["Price"].str[1:].astype(float)`, and if you want integers specifically: `car_sales["Price"].str[1:].astype(float).astype(int)`.  Given that the values are already strings, you can remove the first character ("$") and convert the rest of the string to numeric type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `regex=True` as parameter of [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). However, why do you remove the decimal point? Convert as `float` instead of `int` or chain both or use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `downcast`.

```
car_sales['P1'] = car_sales['Price'].str.replace('[\$\,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)

car_sales['P2'] = car_sales['Price'].str.replace('[\$\,]', '', regex=True).astype(float).astype(int)

car_sales['P3'] = pd.to_numeric(car_sales['Price'].str.replace('[\$\,]', '', regex=True), downcast='integer')
```

Output:

```
>>> car_sales
       Price      P1    P2    P3
0  $4,000.00  4000.0  4000  4000
1  $5,000.00  5000.0  5000  5000
```

Obviously, if you also want to remove the decimal point as described by @wjandrea, you can simply modify the regex:

```
car_sales['P4'] = pd.to_numeric(car_sales['Price'].str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '', regex=True), downcast='integer')
```

Output:

```
>>> car_sales
       Price      P1    P2    P3      P4
0  $4,000.00  4000.0  4000  4000  400000
1  $5,000.00  5000.0  5000  5000  500000
```

Comment: Storing currency as cents as ints is a common way to avoid having to deal with floating-point precision, like `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`. Cf. [What class to use for money representation?](/q/1406737/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea. Thanks for this insightful comment (as usual). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Converting str to int

You're trying to filter out some characters.

I'd suggest the opposite approach : keeping only a subset of characters. It's easier to list the characters you'd want to keep rather than listing the characters you don't want.

For instance with a list comprehension :

```
>>> my_str_price = "$22,000.00"
>>> int("".join([c for c in my_str_price if c.isdigit()]))
2200000
```

#### Explanations about the code :

```py
int( # Will convert parameter to int
    "".join( # Will concatenate strs from iterable using "" (empty string) as separator.
        [ # This list comprehension will give you an array of filtered chars
            c for c in my_str_price
            if c.isdigit() # Condition to keep a character
        ]
    )
)
```

Please however note that this result would give the number of cents in that specific case, but only if you constantly have two digits after the `'.'`. So formatting errors could lead to errors, which might make you want to consider the following approach:

### Converting into a float

For this, just keep the `'.'` in addition to digits and convert the result into float rather than int.

```
>>> my_str_price = "$22,000.00"
>>> float("".join([c for c in my_str_price if c.isdigit() or c == '.']))
22000.0
```

If you really want an integer, you could also just convert the float to an int with the relevant approximation. Like [`math.ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) or [`math.floor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor).

### Note:

List comprehensions are a solution but you could also use a function like [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into the same problem (11/03/24).

this is what found out:

You don't need to replace the "\$ \, \." with blank space anymore you can directly just-->

```
car_sales['Price'] = car_sales['Price'].astype(float)
#or
car_sales['Price'] = car_sales['Price'].astype(int)
```